# Need help in understanding order of evaluation of expression in C

Tags: c

I have troubles understanding how expression is evaluated in the below code.
I do not understand how code works here

```
while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
        ;
```

and why do we need

```
s[1] = '\0';
```

Full code

```
#include <ctype.h>
int getch(void); 
void ungetch(int);
/* getop: get next character or numeric operand */ 

int getop(char s[])
{    
    int i, c;

    while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t');
    s[1] = '\0';

    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
        return c; /* not a number */ 

    i = 0;

    if (isdigit(c)) /* collect integer part */ 
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()));

    if (c == '.') /* collect fraction part */        
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()));

    s[i] = '\0';
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);

    return NUMBER;    
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Check this out http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: @EJEHardenberg The spiral rule applies to type declarations, not to expressions and order of operations.

Comment: `s[1] = '\0';` : Insurance for Use as a string in the caller.

Comment: The use of `c` and the chaining of the assignments is an attempt at optimising the code, the idea being that `c` is assigned to a register by the compiler whereas s[i] is in memory. With a modern, optimising compiler, you could rewrite this without using `c` and get the same results.

Comment: One thing that hasn't yet been mentioned: please don't write atrocities like this!

Comment: @Skizz `int` must be used so that `EOF` can be distinguished from valid characters  (I'm assuming the `getch` function has the same return specification as `getchar`)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is right associative and therefore `isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch())` will be grouped as
`isdigit( s[++i] = (c = getch()) )`. `getch` will read and assign a `char` to `c` and then `c` is assigned to `s[++i]`.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is the so called chained assignment, see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chained_assignment#Chained_assignment). To understand it, you only need to know that assignment in C has value! Therefore, you can thing of it as equivalent to a one-liner of multiple successive assignment from right to left, as @hacks mentioned.

2.

```
s[1] = '\0';
```

This is a safety concern and a normal coding practice: you always pad the end of a string with '\0' in C. Since the input argument s[] is supposed to be a char array, thus you need to pad it.

Note that

```
s[1] will be overwritten if s[0] is a digit or '.',
```

in which case the 2nd or 3rd while loop will be executed. As before, you also need to pad the s[i] with '\0';

Answer (score 1):

This whole function has a design flaw in that it is not possible to prevent a buffer overflow. It needs to know the size of buffer that `s` is pointing to, to avoid that.

Anyway, `while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()));` has the same meaning as:

```
for (;;)
{
    ++i;
    c = getch();
    s[i] = c;

    if ( ! isdigit(s[i]) )
        break;
}
```

There is a reason that `c` is used instead of just writing `s[++i]  = getch()` .

Here I am assuming that `getch` (not a standard function) refers to some function which has the same return specification as `getchar`, i.e. it returns either `unsigned char` value or `EOF`.

The `int c;` is needed so that `EOF` can be detected. If we did not have `c` then there is no way of performing the test `if ( c != EOF )` at the end of the function.  Doing `s[i] == EOF` would not work because it might mistake a valid character for `EOF` (or `EOF` might be out of range of `char`).

However the code still has a bug. The `isdigit` function expects the same sort of `int` value; i.e. in my unpacked version, the final test should be:

```
if ( !isdigit(c) )
```

I'd guess that the code author knew about the issue with `EOF` but either didn't know about `isdigit`, or assumed his code would only be run on an implementation of it that accepted negative chars.

Writing it more compactly, the line could be replaced with:

```
i = 1;
// ...

while ( isdigit(c = getch()) )
    s[i++] = c;
```

Comment: Thank you. This code is from  Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie - The C programming language. Strange that they have a bug in their book

Comment: They wrote their book a long time before the first C Standard came out. Even though the 2nd edition has some fixups it still has a lot of "old stuff".  Perhaps they were aware while writing this code that they were on a system with plain char being unsigned or something;  however the design of `isdigit` was specifically done to allow it just being a lookup table so perhaps they ought to have noticed!